# Remove data that doesn't meet one of two criteria

Tags: python, if-statement, filter

I've written a short function to remove data from my list provided it's higher than some threshold value (here 0.04) and it works as follows:

```
def remove_noise(time_data, volt_data):

volt_clean = []
time_clean = []

for q in range(0, len(volt_data)):

    if volt_data[q] >=0.04:           
        time_clean.append(time_data[q])
        volt_clean.append(volt_data[q])

return volt_clean, time_clean
```

What I want to do is, instead of having one threshold value, check if the data is greater than one value OR lower than another value I pass to the function. Here's what I've written so far:

```
def remove_noise(time_data, volt_data, sma_max, sma_min):

volt_clean = []
time_clean = []

for q in range(0, len(volt_data)):

    if volt_data[q] >=sma_max:
        or volt_data[q] <=sma_min           
        time_clean.append(time_data[q])
        volt_clean.append(volt_data[q])

return volt_clean, time_clean
```

I want to keep all the elements of `volt_data` that are `>=sma_max` or `<=sma_min` but I'm not sure the correct way to write the syntax as Python is giving me a syntax error with second version I wrote. How would you write this `or` statement? I also tried with `elif` instead of `or` but it still didn't work.

Comment: `volt_data` is list ?

Comment: The checks should both be *before* the colon: `if volt_data[q] >=sma_max or volt_data[q] <=sma_min:`

Comment: yes it is. Would it be better as float?

Comment: thanks jonrsharpe that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syntax error here

```
if volt_data[q] >=sma_max:
        or volt_data[q] <=sma_min
```

Try like this

```
 if volt_data[q] >= sma_max or volt_data[q] <= sma_min:
          ## do Something here
```

Or if you want to check if `volt_data[q]` lies between `sma_max` and `sma_min` then

```
if sma_max <= volt_data <= sma_min:
## do something here
```

Also I would suggest you to use like shown below instead of `for q in range(0, len(volt_data)):` because it's more pythonic. Think over it.

```
volt_data = [2,0.4,0.02,0.05]
for q in volt_data:               # instead of for q in range(0, len(volt_data))
        if q >= 0.04:
                print "Above threshold"
        else:
                print "Below threshold"
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax problem is that your second condition should be before the `:`. You also seem to be only returning data that are outside your range not inside it. You want

```
if volt_data[q] <= sma_max and volt_data[q] >= sma_min:
```

Other things worth pointing out/ unsolicited advice:

- return the lists in the same order that you passed them in.

  ```
  return time_clean, volt_clean
  ```
- You don't need the 0 in a range. it is taken as default.

Comment: Appreciate the tips. I'm looking to keep the values that are outside the range though, as I'm counting everything within the range as noise to be removed.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Your "remove data from my list provided it's higher than some threshold value" is slightly ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

just rectify your indentation, rest is ok :

```
def remove_noise(time_data, volt_data, sma_max, sma_min):

  volt_clean = []
  time_clean = []

  for q in range(0, len(volt_data)):

    if volt_data[q] >=sma_max or volt_data[q] <= sma_min :           
    time_clean.append(time_data[q])
    volt_clean.append(volt_data[q])

  return volt_clean, time_clean
```